# Resources.getIdentifier alternative

Tags: android, performance

I've got some ImageViews (~10) that I'd like manipulate in code. Instead of finding them line by line, I thought about looping and finding the views by the `Resources.getIdentifier` method. However it is discouraged according to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Is there a faster, more efficient method available or would I be better off finding my views manually (without looping)?

Comment: Loop over the ids.  You don't need to loop over the names.

Comment: Im not sure I understand you. Wouldn't I be looping over the ID's if I were to use the getIdentifier method and changing the concatenated value?

Comment: You'd be looping over ids with the findViewByID method.  You make an array of the ids and loop over the array, doing a findViewById on each.  No concatenation necessary.

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, that would be faster. I suppose I can't loop to find IDs, can I? Since they're generated by Android and obtaining them would likely use the getIdentifier method?

Answer (score 2):

**Two alternatives I found so far! (*let's assume your file name is **product_json.json***)**

- You can put a file with file name **product_json** in `res/raw` folder and access as below.

  `val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.product_json)`
- Or, you can put your file in `assets` folder (if not exist already then you're welcome to create one!) as access as below.

  `val inputStream: InputStream = assets.open(getString("project_json")`

**Note**: assets.open("file_name_with_extension)e.g., `assets.open("product_json.json")`

Using point number 1 above is faster than accessing resources using `val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(  resources.getIdentifier(getString(R.string.product_json), "raw", packageName)` as `getIdentifier()` has to go through the iteration over all the string resources. This is very slow and not recommended, thus, IDE static analyzers show the warning of "**Use of this function is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier (e.g. R.foo.bar) than by name (e.g. getIdentifier("bar", "foo", null))**". Using `val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.product_json)` is better because system has to just iterate over raw resources.